# CSRF Token Validation

Tags: django

If I send an AJAX POST request from a button. Do I need to validate the CSRF token in my view or does Django automatically do this for you when it accepts the POST? If not, how do I manually validate it myself?

Also, is it correct that when you create a Form and pass in the request, the Form object will automatically do this validation?

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('#button1').click(function(){
    $.post("/", { 
      unique_id : "{{ unique_id }}",
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',` in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your project `settings.py` then `CsrfViewMiddleware` is automatically validate the `csrf_token`. This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works) also:

> For all incoming requests that are not using HTTP GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
>   or TRACE, a CSRF cookie must be present, and the 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'
>   field must be present and correct. If it isn't, the user will get a
>   403 error.
>
> This check is done by CsrfViewMiddleware.